# Adding named variables in separate Excel cells

Tags: excel, variables, sum, naming

I am creating a game in which an object can have different conditions throughout a level. Each condition has a numeric value. In the left column I have the list of conditions such as RED, GREEN, BLUE, TAN, ORANGE. In the right column I have given each of those conditions a value of 1 through 5.

Using this as a key, I would like to go through the game, level by level, marking down all of the conditions that object encounters per level.

For example, In level 1 the Object can be RED, BLUE, ORANGE. In an Excel row, I want to, in separate cells, mark which conditions are encountered. So B2 would be "RED", C2 would be "BLUE" and D2 would be "ORANGE". Then I want to be able to add up those cells to know what the sum of those condition values are.

I have been able, in Name Manager, to assign values to names but I am unable to add separate cells with the condition names together. I am only able to do this as a equation inside of a single cell using "= RED + BLUE + ORANGE" However, it is then difficult, visually, to see all  of the conditions for each level, it only shows the total value in the cell containing the equation.

Thank you very much for your help. Let me know if any additional clarification is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
=INDIRECT(B2)+INDIRECT(C2)+INDIRECT(D2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming input for Level 1 is on `C1`, then paste `=IF(ISERROR(FIND(A2,$C$1)),0,1)` to `C2`, and drag it down to copy for all colours. Then, for Total Score use `=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C6,$B$2:$B$6)` on `C7`.

[image]